# Get value images uploading in html5 by php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

How can get values images uploading after click on button submit as `$_POST` in php (image upload by html5)?

Example of html5 upload is in the **[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/domref/file-click-demo.html)**

https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/domref/file-click-demo.html

What do i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP will populate the [`$_FILES` superglobal](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php) with data about uploaded files. The manual has [extended documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) on the subject (although you should, obviously, ignore the part about submitting a form since you are using JavaScript instead).

Comment: I try in php code as: `print_r($_FILES);` and get in the output this result: http://pastebin.ca/2251829 ... What do i do?